# adobe acrobat pro document sizes

Tags: macos, pdf, printer, printing, adobe-acrobat

Is there seriously no way to take a PDF that is a larger size and simply change it to 8.5x11?

It's an InDesign file. Resizing it in indesign will be a real pain because i only have CS3.

I can't print to a pdf because i'm on leopard OS and the printer just "pauses" or that would be my solution.

I just downloaded the trial to the newest acrobat pro and I am just so shocked there's not a way to just go in and change the document size.

Tell me there is please? Or someone help with a fix to the "paused" printer?

Answer (score 0):

PDFs are considered "Final" documents, so with you being unable to print and "Fit to page size":

File --> Save as --> Image

Then resize the image or create a new 8.5 x 11 PDF with that image file.